# Can I use a backreference to indicate the amount of repetition I want?

Tags: regex

I have some text:

```
q-11-A5zXp93Dnro
```

I would like to use a regular expression like the following to capture the text:

```
(.)-(\d+)-(.{\2})
```

Is using a captured number in that fashion supported at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not supported, at least from my tests [at RegexR](http://regexr.com/3erlb). The braces are just accepted as normal characters. This is probably because there is no way to ensure a number is captured, as Regex capture strings.